# Isabelle: prove that this set notation of a matrice results in a finite set

Tags: isabelle

I am using the **development version of Isabelle** from the repository. I hope it is a good decicion. Sledgehammer is again greatly improved! The isabelle developpers are really great! The reason for the dev version is that Isabelle2013-2 was crashing too often.

How can I prove this lemma:

```
lemma finite_f_A:
  fixes A :: "('a::comm_ring_1 poly)^'n∷finite^'n∷finite"
    and f :: "('a::comm_ring_1 poly) ⇒ nat"
  shows "finite {f (A $ i $ j) | i j. True }"
sorry
```

My old proof that is no longer working with the development version of Isabelle is this:

```
proof-
  have "⋀ K. finite ((λ (i, j). f (A $ i $ j)) ` K)" using finite_imageI by simp
  from this show ?thesis by simp 
qed
```

Comment: I share Andreas opinion that it is in general *not* a good idea to use the development version of Isabelle. But if you do so anyway (and you are not the only one ;)), just mentioning that you *use* it, without giving a changeset id is in general not of great help.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I tought like the dev version at the time of the posting is enough, but I will post it next time.

Comment: I am not aware of really serious problems of Isabelle2013-2 that would render it unusable.  On the other hand, Isabelle2013-1 was I failure, because I misinterpreted the lack of problem reports with lack of problems.  So if there is anything wrong, it is of prime importance to report it on the official Isabelle mailing list, or to the responsible person privately.  Problems that are kept secret will remain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplification procedure `finite_Collect` has been deactivated after the Isabelle2013-2 release in changeset [31afce809794](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/rev/31afce809794), because it sometimes behaves surprisingly or crashes. You can reactivate it with `using [[simproc add: finite_Collect]]` between the lemma statement and the start of your proof. Then, your former proof works again.

By the way, it is in general not a good idea to use the repository version for your work unless you desparately need a new feature or want to participate in the Isabelle development process.

Comment: My experience is that Isabelle2013-2 is simply completely unusable. I get very frustrated, this is not fun. It is slow and crashed too often. With the dev version typing feels again normal, not slightly delayed. Sledgehammer is greatly improved again, it finds proofs faster and the metis proofs are faster too that it generates. People in Munich said using Isabelle dev version is an option to some degree. I don't mind being part of the development process. (I mean with Agda, no one at all uses the stable version.)